# How does one properly manage delete of normalized data when different components rely on the same entity list?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Lets say you have:

- a paginated list of all the books available in your app. You contain that in a `BooksList` component.
- a list of the top books in your app in a `TopBooksList` component.
- all this data that you fetch from a rest api gets normalized and saved in your Redux store, so your store looks something like this:

  `{
    entities: { 
      books: {
        1: { ... },
        2: { ... },
        3: { ... },
        4: { ... },
        5: { ... }
      }
    },
    topBooksList:  [5, 2, 1],
    booksList: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  }`
- A user deletes book `5` by clicking on the delete button on the book in the `BooksList` component

Each time a delete happens, the corresponding entity is deleted from the entities list, and from the results list of that component.

**0.** What is the best way to deal with the fact that there are other components on the page that reference that entity that was just deleted?

**1.** Do you try to coordinate components by adding switch statements for the delete action in every reducer that deals with that kind of data? **1.1** If so, what if you want always make sure to keep in sync a component that ends up affected by that delete, like the `TopBooksList` component in the example. By deleting book `5`, you end up a `topBooksList` of length `2`, what you need it to have a length of 3. Do you somehow mark it as dirty and refetch data? Doesn't this strategy get tedious when the number of related components on the page grows?

**2.** Is there a different, simpler strategy?

Comment: You should look into how data-bindings are done in reactjs (not really familiar with it) or other data bindings (vuejs as example https://vuejs.org/guide/) they have done it pretty nice.

Comment: "Do you try to coordinate components by adding switch statements for the delete action in every reducer" <-- I'm not quite following why your components have anything to do with your reducer? The approach I would take is to have a DELETE_BOOK action which removes the book from the `entities` and the id from `topBooksList` and `booksList` then your `connect()`ed components should reflect that change?

Comment: "DELETE_BOOK action which removes the book from the entities and the id from topBooksList and booksList" => This is done through your reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to add `switch` cases in every reducer that deals with the book. There you do what's necessary to keep everything in order (maintain referential integrity, make sure the top list is 3 long, etc).

However, if this involves fetching data from the backend then this should be placed in the async action creator for `deleteBook`.

The reason for that is that reducers should always be pure, which means they can't have side effects.

In your case I might have a longer `topBooksList` so there's no need to fetch each time a book is deleted. You do not need to display them all.

> Doesn't this strategy get tedious when the number of related
>   components on the page grows?

Yes it does get tedious. Try [Redux-Orm](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm) or [Redux-Schema](https://github.com/ddsol/redux-schema) (disclaimer: written by me).